# find the column index value of last non-infinite float value in rows of a torch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, slice, tensor

```
t = tensor([[2.0000,   -inf, -inf],
            [5.5000, 5.0000, -inf],
            [3.0000, 2.0000, 1.0000]])
```

In the above tensor, for each row, I want to find the column index value of last non-infinite float value. So, in the case of `t`, the output should be, `tensor([[0],[1],[2]])`. How can I do it. It is assumed that in each row, if `-inf` appears, the remaining rest of the row will be `-inf` as well. That is we don't have a case where a row can look like `[5, -inf, 2]`.

Answer (score 0):

First, construct a boolean mask tensor indexing infinities and negate it

```py
mask = t.isinf().logical_not)()
# tensor([[ True, False, False],
#        [ True,  True, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True]])
```

Sum on dim 0 to get the number of non-infinite elements, and subtract from dim 0 length to convert to index:

```py
num_floats = mask.sum(0)
# tensor([3, 2, 1])
indices = mask.shape[0] - num_floats
# tensor([0, 1, 2])
```

and finally unsqueeze to cast to your desired shape:

```py
indices = indices.unsqueeze(1)
# tensor([[0],
#         [1],
#         [2]])
```

---

or, more tidy:

```py
def last_non_inf(t: Tensor) -> Tensor:
    return (t.shape[0] - t.isinf().logical_not().sum(0)).unsqueeze(1)
```